# Insert Script running in web server for Inserting sql data

Tags: sql-server, web, insert

I have a script which is running perfectly in local host. the code is this

```
string sql = "insert into Usertable ";
sql += "values(" + mVendid + ", '" + usrname + "','" + usrpass + "', CONVERT(datetime, " + datecreation + ", 103)" + "," + createdby + ")";
```

The values are `(1,'sa','ee','05/18/2013', 1)`

This is also running fine if I run the same in sql server. But I am having only problem when I am inserting the date field. If I remove teh date field in insert statement the code is running absolutely fine

But while running the same in webserver it is encountering an error as

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Divide by zero error encountered.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: The error is still there. The error is only when I run the same in web server. In Local host it is running fine

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The values passed are (2,'sa','ee','05/18/2013', 1). I am using sqlserver 2008 as database

Answer (score 0):

Using code 103 with `CONVERT` means that you're suppling as input a date in the format dd/mm/yy while in your code you are using mm/dd/yy format.
You could try with these values:

```
(1,'sa','ee','18/05/2013', 1)
```

For further reference about convert function check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) out